# In-app message doesn't show after migration to Hilt

Tags: android, sfdcmobilesdk-android

After migration to Hilt (Activities and Workers), in-app messages stopped being displayed. As I can see from logs push message is getting delivered and `PushMessageManager.handleMessage` returns `true`.

During the implementation of the Hilt, none of the files related to SF was touched. So it can't be an implementation problem. Also, as I said downgrading the SFMC library version fixes issues. Also, handleMessage method returns true, so I believe that something is not working inside SDK. Is it possible to get logs from SDK? Do you use Workers in SFMC SDK?

I use SFMC SDK version `8.0.4`. When I downgrade to version `7.4.2` in-app messages start showing.

**UPDATE**

After investigation I found out that we removed the Android start up library, which initializes the WorkManager by default, since we need to do it on-demand (Hilt requirement) by adding this to Manifest:

```
    <provider
        android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.androidx-startup"
        tools:node="remove">
    </provider>
```

We also started using Hilt worker factory inside Application:

```
class MyApplication : Application(), Configuration.Provider {

...
@Inject lateinit var workerFactory: HiltWorkerFactory
...

override fun getWorkManagerConfiguration(): Configuration =
    Configuration.Builder()
        .setWorkerFactory(workerFactory)
        .build()
...
```

After removing this configuration in-app messages started appearing again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution is to replace  in the manifest with

```
<provider
    android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.androidx-startup"
    android:exported="false"
    tools:node="merge">
    <!-- If you are using androidx.startup to initialize other components -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="androidx.work.WorkManagerInitializer"
        android:value="androidx.startup"
        tools:node="remove" />
</provider>
```